# Ffmpeg and Xing header - iTunes issue and Duration issue

Tags: linux, command-line, mp3, ffmpeg

I extract the audio from a bunch of flv files as an MP3. This works great:

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -vn -acodec copy audio.mp3
```

However, some audio that I extract have durations that are longer than they should be and some MP3 files keep looping the audio! Also in some audio players like WMP, the seekbar gets stuck at one point.

I have found out this is due to Xing headers not being correct or set (?). I was hoping someone could help me edit the above command so this is fixed and maybe some explanation of why this happens so I can learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the above by making sure that I actually converted to an MP3 format rather than just copying the audio codec and assuming its already in MP3 format!!